# PayPal iOS SDK error: PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am facing a problem as follows:

> PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR - System error (PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR). Please try again later. (422) | PayPal Debug-ID: bb4c5a2aef6e6 [live, PayPal iOS SDK 2.3.2]

How can I solve this?

Comment: i think this error is not in list of paypal error codes this might be helpful for you https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/#id09C3E1009E9

Comment: check this also for finding more about error http://restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/422_-_Unprocessable_Entity

Comment: You are in live mode or the test mode ? Either way you need to make sure that your PayPal account is verified and has some funding source attached to it .

Comment: i am testing in live mode and my Paypal account is verified. But in my Paypal account payment is zero.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually indicates an issue with the payer account - like no card available and not enough balance, or no confirmed card if that is required for the payment.  We are in the process now of getting more detailed error codes established to make it clearer what the exact issue is.

Comment: still this error occur . i am change Paypal active account but in my Paypal account credit is zero.
PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR - System error (PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR). Please try again later. (422) | PayPal Debug-ID: bb4c5a2aef6e6 [live, PayPal iOS SDK 2.3.2]

Comment: I checked the Debug-ID you included - the account has no way to fund the payment.  You either need balance in the account, a payment card of some sort, a bank account, etc.  Soon the reason that the payment creation failed will be displayed to the user.